# Returning an int from native function(c++, jni) crashes application

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Trying to figure out why c++ function call returning an int crashes the whole application without any errors/warnings.

Here is working code:

```
    jint Java_org_ntorrent_DummyTorrentInfoProvider_next(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint number)
    {
        jint test = rand();
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "HelloNDK!", "rand() = %d", test);

        return number;
    }
```

And this code crashes application without warnings:

```
    jint Java_org_ntorrent_DummyTorrentInfoProvider_next(
            JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint number)
    {
        jint test = rand();
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "HelloNDK!", "rand() = %d", test);

        return number + test;
    }
```

Before the application crashes i can see my log message(__android_log_print) in log cat

EDIT:
Even if I replace "number + test" with "1" the application still crashing...
It only works if I return "number"...

EDIT#2: Java-side code:

```
package org.ntorrent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class DummyTorrentInfoProvider implements TorrentInfoProvider {

    public native Integer next(Integer number);

    //public Integer next() { return _random.nextInt(); }

    public native void test();

    private Random _random = new Random(100);

    @Override
    public ArrayList getTorrents() {
        test();
        ArrayList torrents = new ArrayList();
        torrents.add(
                new TorrentInfo("test torrent number 1", next(1),  3f, 5f));
        torrents.add(
                new TorrentInfo("test torrent number 2", next(2), 4f, 15f));
        torrents.add(
                new TorrentInfo("test torrent number 555"));
        torrents.add(
                new TorrentInfo("test torrent number 3", next(3), 13f, 5f));
        return torrents;
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: stack smash, or other kind of memory problems?

Comment: Get a dump from the JVM and look what exactly is happening. Under Hotspot there are options to debug these problems - no idea about android though. The code here is fine, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses, guys! I'll try that tomorrow...

Comment: Could these errors be possible if I use wrong version of ndk headers?

Comment: just of out curiosity what happens if you do `test += number; return test`;

Comment: I've updated the question with java code

Comment: That looks fine to me. I can't find fault with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
jint Java_org_ntorrent_DummyTorrentInfoProvider_next(
    JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint number)
```

and

```
public native Integer next(Integer number);
```

Do not match.  An *Integer* is an Object, while an *int* is a primitive.

If your native code uses *jint*, your java code should use *int* in the declaration of the native method.

(If you wish to pass an Integer, you'll need to treat it as a jobject on the native side, and jump through hoops to access it - it's probably easier to use int/jint and do any necessary conversion to from Integer in the java side)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It would be better for me if i read documentation first;) I'll try that out today